# opening multiple profiles at once using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open multiple brave profiles at the same time using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
drivers = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.binary_location = "path to brave.exe"
    option.add_argument(f"--profile-directory=Profile {i}")
    option.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=AppData\\Local\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\User Data")
    s = Service(chromedriver)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=option)
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    drivers.append(driver)
    time.sleep(6)
```

but it only opens 2 profiles out of the four and closes instantly after.
It also gives me the below error:

```
[26088:15656:0312/232753.813:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(157)] :components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(161) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. Please use the `--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management` command line flag to enable it if you are not using the official Google Chrome build.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53952/devtools/browser/cf93ee3c-b9b4-4f89-9dbc-dfdc18107406
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brave.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=option)
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__        
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session    
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In your for loop you append `driver` to `drivers`. From your code I guess that `drivers` is a list. Try to add it into your code. Create the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).